# UIScrollView in UINavigationController can't be top (always 64 margin)

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I embed the scenes into navigation controller, the scene contains a scrollview (called A here, `x=0 && y=64`), and in A, there're another scrollview B (`x=0 && y=0`).
With these position value, scrollview B should be just under the navigation bar. However, actually it has a margin of 64 between scrollview B and navigation bar. Can anyone tell me the reason? Thanks.
 Shown as below (I did nothing in code, purple is A and green is B):

Update:
(the right part is the scene in storyboard, the left is the actual scene. It's totally different.

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @swalkner It's a long time. I remembered I solved, but not in an elegant way. I closed autolayout, and set the position by code. Though it worked then, but may lead to other layout problems later.

Answer (score 0):

You described the problem yourself:

> the scene contains a scrollview (called A here, x=0 && y=64), and in A, there're another scrollview B (x=0 && y=0)

A (x=0 && **y=64**) is 64px down in y coordinate in its superview.

B's superview is A. So B(x=0,y=0) will be placed within A. So, it will be 64px under the navigationbar, as A(x=0, **y=64**).

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Why? B(x=0, y=0) is within A, B should be at the top of A, while it's 64 points under the top of A.

Comment: @Cuero > Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes. I do. Actually, it's the same whether I use autolayout or not.